# Additional symbol LIST when using ,@

Tags: common-lisp, metaprogramming, sbcl

I observed a macro expansion I do not fully understand:

```
(defmacro test (cons-list)
  `(list
     ,@(mapcar #'(lambda(elem)
                   elem)
           cons-list)))


(defmacro test-2 ()
  `(list ,@(list (cons "a" "b"))))


(defmacro test-3 (cons-list)
  `(list ,@cons-list))
```

I'd expect both macros to expand in the same fashion, as I just use mapcar in a fancy way of creating the same list again and then use that list.
But the results observed in SBCL are:

- `(test (list (cons "a" "b")))` expands to `(LIST LIST (CONS "a" "b"))`
- `(test-2)` expands to `(LIST ("a" . "b"))`
- `(test-3 (list (cons "a" "b")))` again expands to `(LIST LIST (CONS "a" "b"))`

Why don't these macro expansions behave the same?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Test-2` evaluates the form `(list (cons "a" "b"))`, the other two do not.

Remember: the arguments to a macro are the forms read, unevaluated.

In order to get the same behaviour from `test-2`, you would have to quote the form: `,@'(list (cons "a" "b"))`.

*EDIT:* Here is a step-by-step expansion of `test`:

```
`(list
  ,@(mapcar #'(lambda (elem)
                elem)
            cons-list))
```

Removing the backquote syntactic sugar:

```
(list* 'list (mapcar #'(lambda (elem)
                         elem)
                     cons-list)
```

Argument substitution in your example:

```
(list* 'list (mapcar #'(lambda (elem)
                         elem)
                     '(list (cons "a" "b")))
```

Evaluate the `mapcar` form:

```
(list* 'list '(list (cons "a" "b")))
```

Evaluate the `list*' form:

```
'(list list (cons "a" "b"))
```

Comment: makes sense but why the additional LIST then?

Comment: All you see is what you put in.

Comment: not exactly. I expected that the @ would expand the list containing the cons. Thus again resulting in a list containing the cons at the end of the macro expension

Comment: You didn't understand the answer, then.  You are actually providing the *extra* `list` yourself to the macro, the one you don't expect.  Try with `(test ("a" . "b"))` and `(test-3 ("a" . "b"))`.  Remember once again, that macro arguments are **not** evaluated, they are the **forms** you provide.